# How do I stop Visual Studio 2013 jumping out of quotes when I type a space in web editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I'm typing the value of an attribute and I hit space, it automatically jumps to the next attribute. I guess this makes sense when typing an id or something but it's really annoying when typing the class attribute with multiple classes. Does anyone know a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Just in case anyone else finds this... According to Visual Studios UserVoice, this has been fixed. I presume in Update 4.

Comment: Confirmed that it's no longer happening in my Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4. Thanks for the heads-up McGaz!

Comment: Very similar issue here, except mine happens when hitting quote to close the attribute (I've got auto-closing disabled). It skips to the next quote in the file instead of entering a quote. Disabling "Auto list members" stops this.
This occurs in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, so unless 2015 fixes this it's still an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior you describe is a function of the IntelliSense "auto list members" feature.  You can work around the annoyance by disabling "Auto list members" for HTML.  Note: you can also do this for other languages.

To disable "auto list members" for HTML go to:

**Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > General:**

uncheck **"Auto list members"**

Unchecking this option will prevent the "jumping" behavior you describe but will also prevent the IntelliSense list from automatically displaying.  Probably not a big deal since you can just press CTRL+J to display it when you need it.

Comment: Great, thanks! Now I have to decide if I need automatic IntelliSense or not. Just a note, in my Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate) the option is actually under **Tools > Options > Text Editor > _Language_ > General**. In my case _Language_ is HTML.

Comment: You are right!  I updated the answer with the correct path to the auto list members option.